# Query works in SSMS but not in SSIS

Tags: ssis

need help guys. I am trying to use the following query to get the data fom a table. It works in SSMS , but in SSIS throws an error.

```
SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 120) AS col1
UNION ALL
SELECT  CAST (CustomerID AS VARCHAR)
FROM    tCustomer
UNION ALL
SELECT  CAST(COUNT(*) AS VARCHAR) AS col1
FROM    tCustomer
```

Throwing the error

```
[OLE DB Source [1]] Error: There was an error with output column "col1" (35) on output "OLE DB Source Output" (11). The column status returned was: "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".
```

What I am trying to achieve is

```
Header line yyyy-mm-dd
 --e.g. 2013-07-01
Data records
Trailer record
---e.g. 13480
```

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: What datatype(size) is destination column?

Comment: string [DT_STR] with length 20.

Comment: Do any of the records have a length greater than 20?

Comment: no. 10 is the condition for it.

Comment: 10 is only the condition for the first, the other two just specify varchar(30) <-- default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you see happens due to data incompatibility.

In first `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10)` you specify the length to `10`

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx) says, that default varchar size is 30, so doing a `CAST(x AS VARCHAR)` equals `CAST(x AS VARCHAR(30))`.
So here we have length of `30`

And finally you have a column, which length is `20`, and here we have a "potential loss of data"

Comment: GREAT !!...  That actually was the problem. Just refreshed it and doesn't give the error any more.